# Using TreeSet contains() in Java with Integers

Tags: java, contains, treeset

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class StepfordHouses {

    private ArrayList<Integer> houses; // A list containing houses
    private TreeSet<Integer> ordered; // An ordered treeset of houses
    private TreeSet<Integer> processed; // Elements already processed
    private String inpline[]; // An array of String holing houses heights in physical order
    private int disorientedindex; // The index for the Street
    private int size; // Number of houses in the Street

    public StepfordHouses() // Constructor for init
    {
        houses = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ordered = new TreeSet<Integer>();
        processed = new TreeSet<Integer>();

        // Basic Input from Text-File (Codechef Requirment)
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    System.in));

            size = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            inpline = br.readLine().split(" ");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("BAAAAAAAAAM!!");
        }

        for (int c = 0; c < size; c++) // Populating Houses
        {
            Integer tmp = Integer.parseInt(inpline[c]);
            houses.add(tmp);
            ordered.add(tmp);
        }
    }

    public int calcIndex() 
    {
        int c = 0;

        while (c < size) {
            Iterator<Integer> it = ordered.iterator();

            Integer h1 = houses.get(c); // Get an element from the raw ArrayList of Houses
            Integer h = it.next(); // Get an element from the Iterator

            while (h1.equals(h) != true) {
                if (processed.contains(h1) == false) { // The element is not already processed
                    System.out.println(h1 + " " + h);
                    disorientedindex++;
                }
                h = it.next(); // Get an element from the Iterator
            }

            processed.add(h1);
            c++;
            it = null;
        }

        return disorientedindex;
    }

}

public class Work {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        StepfordHouses sh = new StepfordHouses();
        System.out.println(sh.calcIndex());
    }
}
```

The contains() method doesn't work the way I expect it to, i.e compare Integers!
The output is 15 , which should be 9 when
 `if(processed.contains(h1)==false)`  works correctly and returns true when an element is already present!

Where could the code be wrong?

Comment: what's the input you're giving it on stdin?

Comment: This is the kind of thing you use a debugger for. I bet you $100 that TreeSet.contains() works just fine, it's just your code that's not doing what you think it does.

Comment: Here is the Input 6
1 4 8 6 3 0

Comment: @Michael Borgwardt Yup, The problem was with my logic! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The logic is flawed. `processed.add(h1);` is called N times but `processed.contains(h1)` is called N*N times. So depending on the input you can have disorientedindex <> N.